# TypeError at /crear-cliente/ in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

**Hello there, I'm trying to do a form that can store the customers records, but recently it's throw me this error**

`TypeError at /crear-cliente/`

`object of type 'int' has no len()`

`C:\Users\G-FIVE\Desktop\practicas y proyectos\mini_erp\MiniErp\customers\views.py`, line 43, in register_customer

36. ```
                address = address
    ```
37. ```
            )
    ```
38. 
39. ```
            customer.save()
    ```
40. ```
            """
    ```
41. ```
            form = FormCustomer(request.POST)
    ```
42. 
43. ```
            if form.is_valid():
    ```

    …
44. ```
                data_form = form.cleaned_data
    ```
45. 
46. ```
                first_name = data_form['first_name']
    ```
47. ```
                last_name = data_form['last_name']
    ```
48. ```
                cedula = data_form['cedula']
    ```
49. ```
                phone_number = data_form['phone_number']
    ```

**I did the form using the Django classes, I'll show you the code of the form, the view and the model**

**Form code:**

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators


# Clase para el formulario de registro de clientes
class FormCustomer(forms.Form):

    # Input para el first_name
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Nombre',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'Ej: John',
                'class': 'form-control form-control-user mb-3',
                'id': 'first_name'
            }
        ),
        validators= [
            validators.MinLengthValidator(3, 'El nombre está incompleto')
        ]
    )


    # Input para el last_name
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Apellido',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'Ej: Doe',
                'class': 'form-control form-control-user mb-3',
                'id': 'last_name'
            }
        ),
        validators= [
            validators.MinLengthValidator(3, 'El nombre está incompleto')
        ]
    )


    # Input para la cédula
    cedula = forms.IntegerField(
        label='Cédula',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'xx xxx xxx',
                'class': 'form-control form-control-user mb-3',
                'id': 'cedula'
            }
        ),
        validators= [
            validators.MinLengthValidator(7, 'Faltan números'),
            validators.MaxLengthValidator(8, 'Has introducido más números')
        ]
    )


    # Input para el teléfono
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(
        label='Teléfono',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'04xx xxx xx xx',
                'class': 'form-control form-control-user mb-3',
                'id': 'phone_number'
            }
        ),
        validators= [
            validators.MinLengthValidator(11, 'Faltan números'),
            validators.MaxLengthValidator(11, 'Has introducido más números')
        ]
    )


    # Input para la dirección
    address = forms.CharField(
        label='Dirección',
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control form-control-user mb-3',
                'style': 'min-height: 150px; max-height: 150px;',
                'id': 'address'
            }
        )
    )
```

**View code:**

```
# Vista que se encarga de registrar al cliente (C)
def register_customer(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = FormCustomer(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data_form = form.cleaned_data

            first_name = data_form['first_name']
            last_name = data_form['last_name']
            cedula = data_form['cedula']
            phone_number = data_form['phone_number']
            address = data_form['address']

            customer = Customer(
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                cedula = cedula,
                phone_number = phone_number,
                address = address
            )

            customer.save()

            return redirect('home')

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect('create_customer')
```

**Model code:**

```
# Clase para la tabla Cliente
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nombre(s)')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Apellido(s)')
    cedula = models.IntegerField(max_length=8, verbose_name='Cédula')
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, verbose_name="Teléfono")
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name='Dirección')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Creado el")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Actualizado el")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cliente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

**I'd like that someone can give me a little help**

I have tried to look for examples and I have seen code similar to mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `MinLengthValidator` and `MaxLengthValidator` on the IntegerFields, which tries to use the `len()` function on integers. This is not possible. Therefore, your `cedula` and `phone_number` fields will produce the `object of type 'int' has no len()` error. You can either look into using `MaxValueValidator` and `MinValueValidator` with `integer` for validators instead of `MinLengthValidator` and `MaxLengthValidator` or change the fields to `CharField`.

I'm not sure what `cedula` is, but I would recommend making `phone_number` a string. Phone numbers are not considered integers and can have special characters, such as adding a area code.

Comment: I could to solve the problem by removing the validators on the Integer Fields, I'm very thankful with your answer and I'm going to implement your recommendation on `cedula` and `phone_number`. Thanks a lot!!!